# plupload - send another request parameter with uploaded file

Tags: javascript, file-upload, upload, plupload

[plupload](http://plupload.com/) creates nice ids in [file object](http://plupload.com/plupload/docs/api/index.html#class_plupload.File.html). How this id can be sent to the upload script?
The upload script has 3 variables in `$_POST` - file name, chunk number and total number of chunks.

**How to add another parameter to plupload's POST request (in my case, the file.id)?**

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The first step would be to add a handler to the `BeforeUpload` event.

Then, if you are using multipart, you can change the uploader settings to dynamically set different multipart params:

```
plupload_instance.bind('BeforeUpload', function (up, file) {
    up.settings.multipart_params = {fileid: file.id}
});
```

(warning: this example overrides any and all multipart_params, you can play it smarter than that by just setting fileid)

if you are not using multipart, your only options would be to pass the argument as a header, or to manually add the param to the URL for each file (these 2 options should also be done within BeforeUpload).
Note that when not using multipart, plupload will add the `name` and `chunk` params to the URL *after* any URL you already set for the uploader, for each file, so this is where extra params go.

Comment: thanks. I don't like multipart uploads as they are not 100% supported. The idea to modify URL is great! But note that `name` and `chunk` are going in the POST, not in the URL.