# How to save files to a specific folder using Plupload plugin?

Tags: php, plupload

I'm using plupload jquery plugin to upload files to my server, how can I change the path where to save the file based on the user's input? (I also included a select dropdown input at the ui page, I need to change the path of file getting saved based on that POST result).

Comment: Probably this answer can help you - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9015944/plupload-send-another-request-parameter-with-uploaded-file. You just need to listen for "BeforeUpload" event and in this listener define multipart_params property of the uploader.

Comment: If you encounter problems with multipart params, maybe this can be of some help http://stackoverflow.com/a/13382331/1236044